# Why is the Coulomb taken as the unit positve test charge, though $1 C$ charge is a high value?

Tags: charge, units, si-units

Why is the Coulomb taken as the unit positve charge, though $1 C$ charge is a high value?

Answer (score 2):

In days when people didn't know electrons even existed, they had to come up with a convenient way to define charge - something that would allow other people to reproduce the same number in another part of the world.

They came up with the Coulomb as "the charge that flows when 1 Ampere of current flows for 1 second".

Nice big round easy number. You can always add micro, nano, pico...

So - what make an Ampere easy to measure? Well two definitions - one the force exerted between two current carrying wires of a certain length and distance apart; another, the mass of silver deposited per unit time when electrolyzing a silver nitrate solution. These were experiments people could replicate elsewhere - and that is what ties it all together.

From wiki:

> The "international ampere" was an early realization of the ampere, defined as the current that would deposit 0.001118000 grams of silver per second from a silver nitrate solution. Later, more accurate measurements revealed that this current is 0.99985 A.

Comment: And note that 1 ampere of current (~ 1 light bulb) is neither an extremely large nor extremely small amount of current. In fact it's a very ordinary amount.

Comment: I always thought the coulomb is a big unit, relative to the MKS units.  With units of that size, you'ld expect a smaller unit, like 1/10 C.

Comment: @wendy.krieger - interestingly, there was [a closely related definition of Ampere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abampere) which was defined as the current that generates two dynes of force per cm for two wires that are one cm apart. It still exists - called the Abampere - but at 10x the value of the "normal" Ampere, it would lead to a unit charge that's also 10x… the world is conspiring against you! Maybe we should all move to the statCoulomb - it is nice and small (3E9 statC ~ 1C)

Answer (score 1):

A test charge is taken to represent one unit by convention.  Test charges are used to measure things like voltage or field.

If you use cgs units, you would put a franklin, and field (E) translates directly into dynes.  If you use SI units, a charge of 1 coulombs turns 'volts/metre' directly into 'newtons'.

It's just a convention.  The coulomb/verber/franklin/biot-second, by being a test charge, is not supposed to intefere with what's being tested.

Comment: I think you might be confusing "unit charge" and "test charge". Or I simply read the question differently.

Comment: @Floris You read the notion that 1 C is large.  The actual question is 'why is a test charge equal to the unit charge'.  The usual way people use test quantities, is to use a unit, because it produces eg E from e V/m to e N.

Comment: @wendykrieger - I read this question on my phone. Now that I'm looking at it on a real screen, the wording that you responded to is staring me in the face… Your reading makes more sense to me now.